Flashlight toggle issue: Android app only turns on the flashlight, not off
I'm developing an Android app that should toggle the flashlight on or off when the app starts. The goal is to switch the flashlight to the opposite state of what it was when the app was launched. However, my implementation only turns the flashlight on and does not turn it off if it was already on.
Here’s the code I'm using:
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FlashlightToggleActivity extends Activity {
    private CameraManager cameraManager;
    private String cameraId;
    private boolean isFlashlightOn = false;

    private final CameraManager.TorchCallback torchCallback = new CameraManager.TorchCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTorchModeChanged(String cameraId, boolean enabled) {
            super.onTorchModeChanged(cameraId, enabled);
            isFlashlightOn = enabled;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            for (String id : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
                if (cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(id).get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE)) {
                    cameraId = id;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (cameraId == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Flashlight not available on this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

        cameraManager.registerTorchCallback(torchCallback, null);
        toggleFlashlight();
    }

    private void toggleFlashlight() {
        try {
            cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, !isFlashlightOn);
            Toast.makeText(this, !isFlashlightOn ? "Flashlight turned on" : "Flashlight turned off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error toggling flashlight: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } finally {
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        cameraManager.unregisterTorchCallback(torchCallback);
    }
}

Issue:
The app correctly turns on the flashlight if it was off, but if the flashlight was already on when the app started, it does not turn it off.
It seems to me that the reason is the isFlashlightOn flag, which is supposed to keep track of the flashlight state, but it looks like the onTorchModeChanged callback may not have time to update isFlashlightOn before toggleFlashlight is called. I tried to do different ways of implementing it, but my skills are not enough to solve the problem

I have seen this happen before. As far as i know the conflict is caused by a system process having control of the flashlight before your app is trying to toggle it off. Your code is not the problem, you need to end all system processes which can control the flashlight before trying to toggle it off. I don't know exactly how you would do this but it wouldn't require root access. simply a function that checks the flashlight status flag and if it's on, kills all system processes that can exhibit flashlight control, then toggles the flashlight off.

Thank you for your answer! However, it seems that the problem is different. If you change the value of the isFlashlightOn boolean variable to true, the program can turn off the flashlight. But then another problem arises: the flashlight cannot be turned on.
